# Show NavigationDrawer on top of ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I am using Androidhibe NavigationDrawer and SwipeTab with Custom Action Bar as seen here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

The NavigationDrawer is shown over the ViewPager (below the ActionBar) but I would like it to show on top of the ActionBar. How can I achieve that affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` to achieve that.

[Here is a blog post](http://mrengineer13.com/how-to-use-toolbar-to-replace-your-actionbar/) that may help you from switching over to Toolbar.

The XML for your MainActivity would look something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The XML for my Toolbar looked like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

I struggled with it at first, but once I switched over to using Toolbar the Navigation Drawer overlayed the Toolbar just like I wanted. If the blog post and sample code here is not enough, just let me know and I can continue to help you through it.

Comment: thnx , but this isn't work for me .... i use swipeable tab , and add tabs to action bar   :http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: @javabeginner perhaps you can use TabLayout with the Toolbar instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html